# nvm install fails to Append nvm source string

Tags: nvm

I downloaded NVM (on Mac High Sierra), with:

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
```

download works, but then there's an error:

```
Appending nvm source string to /Users/User/.bashrc
bash: line 353: /Users/User/.bashrc: Permission denied
=> Appending bash_completion source string to /Users/User/.bashrc
bash: line 360: /Users/User/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

How can I grant it permission - or manually add the strings to .bashrc? And if so what does the string need to be?

Comment: What type of installation did you make? by script, by git, or manual?

Comment: I used wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines you are looking for are the following:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Append them at final of you `.bashrc`.